# Why is the curl of an electric field zero?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, work, conservative-field

I'm asking this question only to make sure that my understanding is correct.

I know that that curl of an electric field produced by a stationary charge is zero and I also know that that work done in moving another charge in an electric field along a loop is zero.

Now since the work done along a close contour is zero, can I attribute this is the reason to be for the curl of an electric field being zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curl of an electric field is given by the Maxwell-Faraday Equation:

$$\nabla \times \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$$

When there is no time varying magnetic field, then the right hand side of the above equation is 0, and the curl of the electric field is just 0.

When the curl of *any* vector field, say $\vec{F}$, is identically 0, we say that the field is conservative.

One property of any conservative vector field is that the closed loop line integral of the vector field around *any* closed path is 0.

$$\oint_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S} = 0$$

The reverse is also true. Whenever it is the case that the integral above is 0 for any closed loop path, then the field $\vec{F}$ is conservative.

> Now since the work done along a close contour is zero, can I attribute this is the reason to be for the curl of an electric field being zero.

Yes, the two formulations are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the vectorfield is conservative and has zero curl follow from the fact that it's the gradient of a potential. Since if $\mathbf{E} = \nabla \phi$ then
$$
\int_{\mathbf{r}_1}^{\mathbf{r}_2} \nabla \phi\, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} = \phi(\mathbf{r}_2) - \phi(\mathbf{r}_1)
$$
so if the curve is closed then the work done is zero. The curl is also zero since
$$
\nabla \times \nabla\phi = \varepsilon_{ijk} \mathbf{e}_i \partial_j \partial_k \phi = 0
$$
because you can change the order of the derivatives.

Also note that zero curl doesn't imply the existence of a potential since the region in which the vector field is defined needs to be a star domain.

In general I don't think Stokes' theorem
$$
\int_{\partial F} \mathbf{v}\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} = \iint_{F} \nabla\times\mathbf{v}\, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}
$$
is applicable, because the electric field has a singularity at 0 which is inscribed by $\partial F = \gamma$, so you cannot directly infer zero curl from the conservative property.

Comment: Does it work the other way around, that is can we say that $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}=\textbf{0}$ and therefore $\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla} $ V?

Comment: No, $\nabla \times E = 0$ only implies that $E = - \nabla V$ locally. A sufficient condition is that the domain is star shaped or simply connected (Poincaré's lemma).